# Multiplace instances of an object in Game Maker with a variable changing

Tags: game-maker

I want to do a level selection menu in GameMaker. There's one button for each level. Clicking on the button 1 take you to level 1, button 2 take you to level 2 and so on.

But if I duplicate the first button, all of the buttons will get you to level 1. Is it possible for multiple instances of the same object to have different variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you placed all the buttons in the room editor then you can define variables in [instance creation code](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20rooms/index.html) (room editor -> RMB on an instance -> Creation Code).

If you created all the buttons via code, you can easily define different values, like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    var obj = instance_create(50 + i*50, 50, obj_button);
    obj.level = i; // all the instances will has different value
}
```